# SELECT, JOIN, and a WHERE != statement returning too many rows

Tags: mysql

Trying to get a tricky mysql select statement working - and I need some help to cool off my burning noggin...and I have a feeling one of you MYSQL heroes out there will look at this and reel it off.

Goal:  List a given user's songs NOT in a given category.

Three tables: : 
table 1: song, many fields with assigned UserID, and unique SongID

table 2: category, 3+ fields, with assigned UserID and unique CatID

table 3: linker, one-to-many for listing songs in one or more categories. 3 fields, unique id (index), SongID, CatID

The following gets me close - but does not list a user's songs that aren't assigned to any other category at all OR are a already assigned to a another category (I think thanks to !=).

```
SELECT DISTINCT song.SongName, song.UserID, song.SongID  FROM song  
JOIN linker ON song.SongID = linker.SongID 
WHERE  linker.CatID != 155 AND song.UserID =2
```

Then, I tried this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT song.SongName, song.UserID, song.SongID FROM song 
LEFT JOIN linker ON song.SongID = linker.SongID 
WHERE (linker.SongID IS NULL OR linker.CatID != 155) AND song.UserID =2
```

Closer but not working (still thanks to != including songs already assigned).

I was thinking I can get away without invoking table 2, since it merely adds and defines categories for a given user.  Alternatively, I'm thinking of getting all the user's songs, and then unsetting array values with a given CatID - but this doesn't seem like it should be necessary?    I feel like I'm missing something simple? Table structure is not sacred at this point if it absolutely needs to change.  Thanks to any who share their thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I am used to MSSQL so if my syntax is off, appologies in advance):

```
SELECT s.SongName, s.UserID, s.SongID
FROM song s
LEFT JOIN linker l on s.SongID = l.SongID AND l.CatID = 155
WHERE s.UserID = 2
AND l.ID is null
```

Comment: It works!  Now (with humility), can you give a brief description of how/why? Very cool.  My sincerest appreciation and thanks!

Comment: @Chuck It works by grabbing all the songs and then joining in the records for the category you want to exclude.  By using a left join it keeps all the songs that are unassigned and those which are assigned, but not to the excluded category.  By putting the l.CatID in the join clause it makes sure that the only records that get joined are the ones in the excluded category and not any of the other ones.  This means that the result set will have l.ID is null for any song that doesn't have a linker record with CatID = 155.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT song.SongName, song.UserID, song.SongID 
  FROM song 
  LEFT JOIN linker 
    ON song.SongID = linker.SongID 
   and linker.CatID != 155 
   AND song.UserID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work.  let's through other UserIDs in songs and  the linker rows that are != but are assigned to other categories (I don't think I can keep the != - but don't know the alternative...

Comment: That TSQL should NOT be be returning other UserIDs. Post your full database definitions and sample data to reproduce the problem.